# how to convert this JSON format into model class and get response into list using retrofit

Tags: android, json, api, retrofit, retrofit2

```
    {
  "data": [
    {
      "resource": "teams",
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Pakistan",
      "code": "PAK",
      "image_path": "https://cdn.sportmonks.com/images/cricket/teams/1/1.png",
      "country_id": 190324,
      "national_team": true,
      "updated_at": "2018-11-29T11:47:20.000000Z"
    }
]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have something like this

```
public class Response{
    private List<Data> data;
    // getter and setter
}

class Data{
    private String resource;
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String code;
    @SerializedName("image_path")
    private String imagePath;
    @SerializedName("country_id")
    private long countryId;
    @SerializedName("national_team")
    private boolean nationalTeam;
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    private String updatedAt;

    // getters and setters
}
```